# Load file with django manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, gensim

I'm using Django for a search engine. Requests are made by POST, the server treats them and answers with JSON format. In order to be fast, I need to have an index file loaded at the beginning (with manage.py runserver) and a way to access it when a view is called.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: search requests should use the GET method.

Comment: yeah but data sent by GET are limited to ~8500 characters (unless you recompile Apache...) which is not enough for what I'm doing

Comment: You mean your querystring is bigger than ~8500 charecters ??? That's huge...

Comment: yep I'm looking for articles in a database which are semantically close to a text given in argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the index file at process startup means you'll have to restart your process(es) each time the index file changes. You'd be better running a dedicated process as the "search engine" and have your Django application communicate with this process (hint: you probably want a json document database, really).

But anyway: to have your index loaded at process startup, the simplest way is to do it in one of your models files - then your view can just import it from the models file.

Comment: Actually the index file changes only once a month, so it's ok.
By loading in one of model files, you mean something like :
`index = similarities.docsim.Similarity.load(index_file)` (this is how the index is loaded) in models.py ? But then, each time the view is called, the file is loaded again right ? This is what I'm trying to avoid, because loading this file is quite slow.

Comment: Django is not PHP and (unless your server setup is *very* weird) you have one or more long-running processes serving your app (IOW: you don't have the whole damn thing reloaded for each and any request). A module is only "loaded" once per process (here again: unless you're doing something weird - not that with django's dev server your model modules might be loaded twice on startup). So, if you load your index file *at the module's top level* it will only get loaded once per process.